# PayPal API Not Working All The Time Anymore

Tags: php, api, paypal

Most of our API calls work successfully and store into our database but a few don't. I've collected some logs and we're getting a 'Error 400 Bad Request'.

--

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101: Connection: close

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101: Content-Length: 11

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101: content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101:

[29-Sep-2020 08:04:48 UTC] not verified Error 101: Bad Request

--

Logs: https://pastebin.com/hRjrgWGd

Code:

```
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "HOST: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Connection close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//$fp = fsockopen ('ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
    echo "error";
    error_log("FAILED line 53");

} else {
    // NO HTTP ERROR

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);


    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);

        if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            //Setup Required Variables
            $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $cust_name = $first_name .' '. $last_name;
            $cust_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $cust_id = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];
            $cust_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
            $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
            $currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];

            $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
            $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
            $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
            $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
            $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
            $address_status = $_POST['address_status'];

            $g_ref = "";

            if (isset($_POST['fulfillment_order_reference_number'])) {
                $g_ref = $_POST['fulfillment_order_reference_number'];
                $address_street = $_POST['fulfillment_address_line1'];
                $address_city = $_POST['fulfillment_address_city'];
                $address_state= $_POST['fulfillment_address_state'];
                $address_zip = $_POST['fulfillment_address_zip'];
            }

            $item_count = $_POST['num_cart_items'];

            //Misc Variables Requried for Authentication
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
            $our_email = '###'; #PP EMAIL HERE
            $our_email_2 = '###'; #PP EMAIL HERE

            if (($payment_status == 'Completed') && (($receiver_email == $our_email) || ($receiver_email == $our_email_2)))
            {
                //Check Transaction Not Already Processed
                //  $check = $db_query->duplicate_check($txn_id);
                //  if ($check != 0) { exit(); }

                //Distinguish between accounts
                if ($receiver_email == $our_email) {
                    $pp_acc = "CB";
                } else if ($receiver_email == $our_email_2) {
                    $pp_acc = "IK";
                }

                for ($n=1;$n<=$item_count;$n++) {
                    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'. $n];
                    $item_quantity = $_POST['quantity'. $n];
                    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'. $n];
                    $total_paid = $_POST['mc_gross_'. $n];
                    error_log("HIT ADD ORDER tx: $txn_id");

                    //Add Order to DB (Removed)
                }
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            error_log("Invalid Error 102");

        }
        else {
            // This is where it seems to be hitting
            error_log("not verified Error 101: " . $res);
        }
    }
}

fclose ($fp);
```

It seems that feof($fp) reads to the end of the request data but the ones not saving to the database are not hitting the VERIFIED 'if' statement and rather 'else'.

I've checked PayPal IPN history and all requests have been sent successfully, so it's definitely our server issue. This were not issues in 2016 to 2018, but ever since then we have had some that do not save into our database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [IPN Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/#ipn-listener-request-response-flow), ensure you include a `User-Agent:`  field in your request headers, with a value that is any string more than 7 characters or so

You also should be using an HTTPS/SSL connection (standard port 443) to `ipnpb.paypal.com`, not sure why your code is using the older `www.paypal.com` endpoint for IPN.

Comment: Ok, so how would I change this? 
 $header .= "HOST: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
 $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Comment: Apparently you need to change the www in two places, and also add the new user-agent header separately